# mup setup : Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake

Tags: meteor, mup

Problem here is when I am trying to run command mup setup
there is error,where I am going wrong

```
Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[54.186.xx.xxx] - Setup Docker
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

My mup.js file looks like below

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '54.186.xx.xxx',
      username: 'ubuntu',
      pem: '~/.ssh/mypem.pem'
    }
  },
  app: {
    name: 'myapp',
    path: '/var/www/meteor/myapp',
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://ec2-54-186-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp',
      PORT: 3027,
    },
    docker: {
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base',
    },
    deployCheckWaitTime: 60,
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },
  mongo: {
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  }
};
```

Meteor version is 1.6.
[image]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing looks wrong with your `mup.js` file.

The problem may be that you cannot SSH with your current IP address. For instance, if you are using AWS, make sure that in the security groups your current IP address have access to it.

Comment: Thank you. SSH source was set to my ip, I changed it to anywhere and also set the elastic ip address , and bind it with my instance of interest. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is happening exactly, but there are a few potential issues:

```
deployCheckWaitTime: 60,
```

You could make this longer, eg 90 or 120 to give it more time to deploy (in case that is a problem)

```
path: '/var/www/meteor/myapp',
```

This might be the cause of the problem. Usually it is a relative path to the source code of the app, not where you deploy to, so typically it is something like `../app`

```
ROOT_URL: 'http://ec2-54-186-xx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
```

Presumably you are intending to use something like http://myapp.com/ for your app - that's what should go here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Changed from deployCheckWaitTime: 60 to deployCheckWaitTime: 600, but still no breakthrough. And we are having '/var/www/meteor/myapp' this kinda path for other servers and they are working fine. I have referred [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lyyh2fkXovo&t=427s) for root url.

Comment: The root url is used to let the server know where it's base URL is. Using an AWS url will 'work', but it will always revert to this, and once you get into production you want a proper URL, right?

Comment: The `path` config item should point to the git repo on your hard drive. I doubt that `/var/www/meteor/myapp` is where it lives. Try it and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: Hey mate, can you just have a look at the image, I have just added and tell me whether I am going right.

Comment: It looks like a Meteor project ok, are you sure you have write access to the full project? It is the usual convention to checkout a repo to your home directory, and work from there. `/var/www` is usually owned by a special user which is created for the web server to run as. This user has very limited access to the computer (for security reasons). So my preference would be to move the repo to your home directory and do your development work from there. If you have to leave it where it is, then make sure that the full directory tree is writable by your user account

Comment: You was right, path var/www was also one of the issues related to permissions. Finally moved to ~/meteor/app. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, can you mark my answer as correct please?

Answer (score 1):

In security groups, SSH source rule was MY IP, which I changed to anywhere  then created elastic ip and bind it with instance. And now I can access login.

One can use [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/get-a-domain/) to get help.

Answer (score 0):

check your host ip.
I had same issue changing host ip fixed it for me.
Ip changes when you restart your VM es2 client.