# (Meteor) Mup deploy "read ECONNREST Error"

Tags: meteor

I don’t know what is going on.

I reinstalled my Computer and updated Meteor. I had some permission problems in a earlier problem I could fix that tho. Meteor is normally running if I don't want to deploy it. Deploying used to work just fine btw.

```
mup.cmd deploy --settings settings.json
Building App Bundle Locally

Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor App
[82.165.207.55] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server
[82.165.207.55] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to the Server: SUCCESS
[82.165.207.55] - Prepare Bundle
[82.165.207.55] - Prepare Bundle: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Configuring App
[82.165.207.55] - Pushing the Startup Script
[82.165.207.55] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
[82.165.207.55] - Sending Environment Variables
[82.165.207.55] - Sending Environment Variables: SUCCESS

Started TaskList: Start Meteor
[82.165.207.55] - Start Meteor
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled ‘error’ event
^

Error: read ECONNRESET
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at TCP.onread (net.js:615:25)
```

What does that mean? I couldn’t find any solution for my problem online. Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> This error can happen if your IP address cannot SSH. Make sure your IP
>   hasn't changed, or change your rules/IP in the security groups of the
>   service you are using.

There was another case of this recently here [mup setup : Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354172/mup-setup-error-timed-out-while-waiting-for-handshake)

But I don't think he sorted it out. He has also reported it on the mup issues list

You can also enable debugging and set mup to be verbose like this:

```
DEBUG=mup* mup <command> --verbose
```

(docs at http://meteor-up.com/docs.html)

Comment: It happens not while it is trying to set up the docker tho :/

Comment: So did you try ssh-ing to your server to see if  that works? Did you try it in verbose mode to see if more information is forthcoming?